# How to configure realUrl 2.1.x to prevent unwanted enties in tx_realurl_urldata

Tags: typo3-7.6.x, realurl

We have a multi langauge setup for our homepage

```
en.html is mapped to index.php?L=0
```

and
    de.html is mapped to index.php?L=1

Rootpage ID = 76
5 Years with realUrl 1.x.x worked fine .. Until upgrading to 2.1.x i got some strange effekts. f.e.:

Today it happened that the following entry was stored into tx_realurl_urldata :

```
original_url= L=1%27A%3D0&id=76 
speaking_url = de.html 
request_variables = {"id":"76","L":"1'A=0"}
```

and the de.html shows the content of the englisch Version. Deleting that row, fixes the problem. But i am shure, this entry will re-appear.

What should be don in Real Url Conf to store only allowed languages  into request Variables . ??

My (custommade) RealUrl Conf File looks like this:

```html
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
 '_DEFAULT' => array(
  'init' => array(
   'enableCHashCache' => 1,
   'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile',
   'enableUrlDecodeCache' => 1,
   'enableUrlEncodeCache' => 1,
   'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
   'postVarSet_failureMode' => '',
  ),

  'cache' => array ( 'banUrlsRegExp' => '/ContactLeadId=|gclid=|type=|(?:^|\?|&)q=/' )

  'redirects' => array(),
  'preVars' => array(
   array(
    'GETvar' => 'L',
    'valueMap' => array(
     // alle sprachen die doch nicht live gehen deaktivieren
     //'en' => 0, //international (needs no url part because its the default language)
     'de' => 1, //germany
     'it' => 2, //italy
     'cz' => 3, //czechrepublic
     'fr' => 4, //france
     'ch_de' => 6, //switzerland - german
     'at' => 7, //austria
     'es' => 18, //spain
     'ch_fr' => 19, //switzerland - french
    ),
    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
   ),
  ),
  'pagePath' => array(
   'type' => 'user',
   'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
   'spaceCharacter' => '-',
   'languageGetVar' => 'L',
   'expireDays' => 7,
   'rootpage_id' => 76,
  ),
```

after that it just follows fixedPostVars, filenames , postVarSets and some definitions for different domains. But i think those settings are not important for the "L=" problem.

Comment: How does you realurl config look like? Did you setup your own custom config or do you use auto generated config. What was the result with the old realurl, a 404 page or was the request just not saved in the realurl cache and was the served page the same like now?

Comment: I added my custom made Real Conf, or better: the in my oppinion important part. f.e: without the with REAL Url 2.x  added value : "cache" => array ( 'banUrlsRegExp' => Entry the Cache is filled "unlimited" with unwanted Marketing Tracking entrys.

Comment: I Created an issue in the realUrl Bug Tracker with a link to a possible patch https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/issues/295